# Why controller class not return jsp page in springBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

> I created just a simle springBoot application,and I want when i lunch
> my application it retun me my jsp page in my browser. but when I type
> localhost:8080 in my browser it return me this type of error"There was
> an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)."I added jasper
> dependency got same error,I use jsp api dependency in place jasper i
> got same error.
> what is the reason i am not getting jsp page as a result,why it throws
> error404
>
> this type of error
> [image]

> project file strcture
> [image]

> HomeController.java

```
package com.main.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String host() {
        return "Katak.jsp";
    }

}
```

> Katak.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 Welcome to security World
</body>
</html>
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>BasicSecurity-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BasicSecurity-2</name>
    <description>Demo project for SpringSecurity</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.37</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: 1. You haven't configured JPS properly, 2. JSP only work in a WAR file not a JAR file, 3. You are returning `Katak.jsp` while it is called `Katakile.jsp` according to your screenshot. I strongly suggest NOT to use JSP but rather something like Thymeleaf or Mustache for your views.

Comment: You actually can use JSP in Jar file as well.. there is no requirement that application must be packaed as WAR. The first problem I see here is, that OP uses Spring MVC @Controller and has a JSP file `Katakile.jsp` but returns another name to the ViewResolver engine.

Comment: With tomcat it doesn't work with a jar you need a war (this is also documented in the Spring Boot docs in the JSP restrictions section).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using proper jsp names, in project structure, jsp name is showing as "Katakile.jsp". But in controller you are returning "Katak.jsp".

If names are proper and still not working, please use "tomcat-embed-jasper" dependency instead of "tomcat-jasper" and remove the tomcat-jasper dependency from your classpath, if exists.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this line

```
 @RequestMapping("/katak")
public String host() {
    return "/Katakile.jsp";
}
```

And try acces localhost:8080/katak